# Django: import causes ImportError only when in try except block

Tags: python, django

I have two modules that import some stuff from each other:

`project/urls.py`:

```
from modules.helpers import helper

urlpatterns = [
    # patterns
]
```

`modules/helpers.py`:

```
def helper():
    # some magic

def main():
    from project.urls import urlpatterns
    # process urlpatterns
```

`modules/__init__.py`:

```
from modules.helpers import main
main()
```

**And everything works fine**, until I wrap `from project.urls import urlpatterns` to look like this:

```
def main():
    try:
        from project.urls import urlpatterns
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

It prints:

> cannot import name 'urlpatterns' from partially initialized module 'urls' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/MaxCore/Documents/www/project/project/urls.py)

What can be the reason?

**EDIT**

In minimal reproducible example everything also works fine, probably exception is related to django somehow. Something changed in import order because of try except block

---

If I specify `modules` in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` (which is not needed), and `runserver` it prints:

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Comment: As the error message mentions, a circular import can be the reason. Did you investigate that?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I wonder why it is not the reason when it is not in try except block

Comment: I see. Can you create a [mre] that doesn’t involve Django, i.e fill in the `# some magic` etc. with the least amount of code to make it run and add a top-level script which calls `main`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 ye, just did it, everything works fine, it's really related to django somehow( have to think

Comment: You changed an absolute import to a relative one in your sample code. Is it deliberate and reflects what you actually did?

Answer (score 0):

I still do not understand the deep reason behind why try-except block changes load order, but I've found a solution:

1. Add `modules` to `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`
2. Create `apps.py` in `modules/` dir with content:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ModulesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'modules'

    def ready(self):
        from module.helpers import main
        main()
```

3. Add `default_app_config = 'core.apps.ModulesConfig'` to `modules/__init__.py`

Comment: So urlpatterns load views, views load models. You're executing this from `__init__`, which is major footshooting, because it will always execute first thing when your app is referenced, before Django has a chance to load the models.